# Flutter - Floating Button inside a popup widget overlaying the scroll

Tags: flutter, user-interface, widget

Im working on my first flutter app so i am still learning possible widgets and how they react in certain structures.

So far I was doing well but cant figure out one thing I want to do.

I want to get a floating button inside of my cupertinopopusurface widget like this.

[image]

My structure is similar, on the home screen I have a listview builder that builds my cards and when you press on each one it opens a cupertinopopupsurface.

Inside I also built a Single child scroll view structure for all my contant and its scrollable but I would to get a button that overlays it all and is in a fixed placed.

My structure currently is

CupertinoPopupSurface/
Container/
SingleChildScrollView/
Column/
Children/
Row/ (all rows now with content)

I cant get the button fixed somewhere in the structure but then it follows the scrolling its now fixed overlaying the contant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stack` widget inside `cupertinopopupsurface` like this:

```
CupertinoPopupSurface(
   child: Stack(
      children:[
         your SingleChildScrollView,
         Positioned(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 16,child: yourbutton),
      ]
    
    )
)
```

Comment: If i want 2 buttons one next to each other? Is the Row inside Positioned or is Positioned inside the row?

Comment: you need put those button inside a row and put that row inside positioned.

Comment: Since I have your attention, could you point me to the direction where I could get more info on how to make the frontend part with 3 profile pictures plus the generic number for rest. I already have the database with users and their images pulled.

Comment: this is another question and not related to this one, please ask another question and I will give your answer there, and also please add your dataList about your pictures there

Comment: Okey I did, sorry new to stackoverflow practices.